# How to write in Python from a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a text file and write to the file but when doing so it's not working at all.

Here's what I have:

```
changeaddress = [changeaddr1, changeaddr2]
address = [address_1, address_2]
new_var = []
cur_addr = 0
with open('address.txt','r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        if address[cur_addr] in line:
            line.replace(address[cur_addr], changeaddress[cur_addr])
            cur_addr += 1
        new_var.append(line)

with open('address.txt','w') as file:
    file.writelines(new_var)
```

what I'm doing wrong? it's not working.
thanks!

Comment: Define *it's not working*. *How* does it not work? Why does it not work - what doesn't work as intended? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? What's the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: Have you made sure your script is executable and your file has accessible permissions.

Comment: @AndrewLi it's just don't work, no errors, it's just don't replace as I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable. `line.replace` returns a new string, not literally replaces it.

```
new_line = line.replace
... 
new_var.append(new_line)
```

Note: storing the whole list in memory will be bad for large files. You can open two files in one `with` command to read from one file, and write to another

Comment: I tried but this isn't working, it's not returning any error when I run my script it's just not replacing

Comment: Probably because you still are writing line, not new line... This is an easy process to debug if you'd just print the values. Get it working before you change your output source

Comment: Thank you, when doing so it deletes the line first line of my .txt leaving just the replaced item. Do you know why is it happening?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are seeing, but, 1) `'r+'` can be removed from the first file. 2) Your code is hard to debug because you completely overwrite the initial file. Try writing to a different one